# Buggy Heap Sort

Tags: python, heap, heapsort

Below is my attempt at Heap Sort which is suppose to resemble what is shown in [CLRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) from page 152 and onward.

If I pass A = [9, 0, 5, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8, 1, 2] as input. The output of BuildMaxHeap is [9, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, 0, 1, 2]. Which seems right. However passing the same input to HeapSort gives me [9, 8, 4, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 0] which is defiantly wrong.

Can anyone shred some light on what I'm doing wrong?

```
def left(i):
    return 2 * i

def right(i):
    return 2 * i + 1

def HeapSize(A):
    return len(A) - 1 

def MaxHeapify(A, i): 
    l = left(i)
    r = right(i)
    if l <= HeapSize(A) and A[l] > A[i]:
            largest = l 
    else:
            largest = i 
    if r <= HeapSize(A) and A[r] > A[largest]:
            largest = r 
    if largest != i:
            A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
            MaxHeapify(A, largest)

def BuildMaxHeap(A):
    for i in range(HeapSize(A) // 2, 0, -1):
            MaxHeapify(A, i)

def HeapSort(A):
    BuildMaxHeap(A)
    for i in range(HeapSize(A), 1, -1):
            A[i], A[1] = A[1], A[i]
            MaxHeapify(A, 1)
```

Comment: I think one of the problems may be that you have a off-by-one error. Array indexes in Python are 0-based, whereas if I recall correctly, they are 1-based in CLRS. So, `A[i], A[1] = A[1], A[i]` should be `A[i], A[0] = A[0], A[i]` and your `range` should go down to `0`. I haven't ran the code yet, it's just a thought.

Comment: You are right and while you updated your comment I updated my code. I thought I already had accounted for it in my ranges... but brb.

Comment: Your `MaxHeapify` seems to be incorrect. If `A = [0, 5, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8, 1, 2, 9]` and call `MaxHeapify(A, 0)` it will change it to `[5, 7, 6, 4, 9, 3, 8, 1, 2, 0]`, which is wrong, right?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. But my left and right functions was wrong and now I just updated them... still wrong end result though.

Comment: Yes, they are ok now. One step at a time :-) Don't forget `range(HeapSize(A), 1, -1)` needs to be `range(HeapSize(A), 0, -1)`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't keep on correcting your code by editing it here. It will make the question use-less for the next person who has the same problem and wants to see what was wrong with your code.

Comment: I did update the range locally. I'll change the code back here... I have it in git. Still wrong result though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52713/discussion-between-s16h-and-user672009)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I saw, some corrections on your original codes (check the comments):

```
def left(i):
    return 2 * i      # this is 1-based tree. Since your first element is stored in 0th cell, here is an error

def right(i):
    return 2 * i + 1    # same, this's 1-based

def HeapSize(A):
    return len(A) - 1 

def MaxHeapify(A, i): 
    l = left(i)
    r = right(i)
    if l <= HeapSize(A) and A[l] > A[i]:
            largest = l       # always keep 4 white space (or tab) as indent in Python, don't mix up
    else:
            largest = i 
    if r <= HeapSize(A) and A[r] > A[largest]:
            largest = r 
    if largest != i:
            A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
            MaxHeapify(A, largest)

def BuildMaxHeap(A):
    for i in range(HeapSize(A) // 2, 0, -1):     # the last non-leaf element is (HeapSize(A)-1) // 2
            MaxHeapify(A, i)

def HeapSort(A):
    BuildMaxHeap(A)
    for i in range(HeapSize(A), 1, -1):   # e.g. range(3,1,-1) gives you [3,2], you miss the 1st element
            A[i], A[1] = A[1], A[i]     # swap with A[0], unless you don't use the 0th element of array
            MaxHeapify(A, 1)      # here is essential error for the algorithm. Since you're doing in-place sorting, you'd not swap the largest element to end of heap then MaxHeapify the WHOLE ARRAY again. I.e. you have to MaxHeapify the heap EXCLUDING the last element
```

Then below is a working version that based on your codes:

```
def left(i):
    return 2 * i + 1

def right(i):
    return 2 * i + 2

def parent(i):     # your 'left' and 'right' function is good practice, keep it
    return (i - 1) // 2

def MaxHeapify(A, heap_size, i): 
    l = left(i)
    r = right(i)
    if l <= heap_size and A[l] > A[i]:
        largest = l 
    else:
        largest = i 
    if r <= heap_size and A[r] > A[largest]:
        largest = r 
    if largest != i:
        A[i], A[largest] = A[largest], A[i]
        MaxHeapify(A, heap_size, largest)      # important: don't always sort the whole array (size of heap keeps decreasing in 'HeapSort')

def BuildMaxHeap(A):
    heap_size = len(A) - 1    # index of last element of the heap
    for i in range(parent(heap_size), -1, -1):    # don't miss i=0 iteration
        MaxHeapify(A, heap_size, i)

def HeapSort(A):
    BuildMaxHeap(A)
    heap_size = len(A) - 1
    for i in range(heap_size, 0, -1):    # ends at i=1. You don't swap A[0] with A[0], right?
        A[i], A[0] = A[0], A[i]
        MaxHeapify(A, i-1, 0)     # careful here: MaxHeapify which part of the array
```

Output of test:

```
>>> a = [9, 0, 5, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8, 1, 2]
>>> BuildMaxHeap(a)
>>> a
[9, 8, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, 0, 1, 2]
>>> HeapSort(a)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: By passing the heap_size to MaxHeapify we avoid sorting the entire array, right?

Comment: Correct, that's the purpose of it